# How to copy or split a SSAS project or datas source view

Tags: visual-studio, ssas

In one of the SSAS solutions that I have inherent there are two cubes using the same data source and data source view. The data source points to database A. Database A contains the tables for both cubes. The issue at hand is that both cubes represent the data from two different ERP systems. Due to no plan  upfront the situations occurred that one database contains the tables for both systems. The server hosting the database is going to be decommissioned, a good moment to reorder the things for the better.

On the new server I want to create separate databases for the ERP systems which results in two different databases containing the data for the cubes.

I now want to split the SSAS project in visual studio so both cubes have their own solution. In order to keep the relational model in the data source view intact I hoped it would be possible to split or copy the view or project.

So, how can I copy or split a SSAS project or datas ource view?

If there are better alternatives to deal with this situation I am open for those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was easy. I just had to create a new branch in Team Foundation Server and remove all projects and attributes that I do not need.